# sequelize not inserting to database, (sequelize, nodejs, mocha, chai)

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sequelize.js, chai

I am using **sequelize** ORM with **node** js and trying to **create a new record in database** in a test case written using **mocha** an **chai**, the test case getting executed and below is the code and out put

but **nothing inserted to database**
i'm expecting a new record in database but it's not inserting

```
const app = require('../../app');
const chai = require('chai');
const should = chai.should();
const expect = chai.expect();
const models = require('../../app/models/index');
const User = models.User;
let assert = chai.assert;

describe('Model:User - attribute: password_digest - unit tests', () => {
  it('password_digest should not be empty', (done) => {
    console.log('>>>1');
    console.log(User.create);
    User.create({
      email: 'aa@gmail.com',
      password: 'aa',
      password_confirmation: 'aa',
      role_id: 'User',
      profile_id: 'Consultant'
    }).then(function(user) {
      console.log('>>>2');
      console.log(user);
    });
    console.log('>>>3');
    done();
  });
});


Model:User - attribute: password_digest - unit tests
test_1           | >>>1
test_1           | [Function]
test_1           | >>>3
test_1           |     Γ£ô password_digest should not be empty
```

Comment: try to print error by adding error function in .then(function(user){},function(error){
 console.log('error')
})

there can be numerous reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `done()` in both your promise handlers, and only there: the fulfilled branch (`then`), so you wait for the Promise to resolve before telling mocha the tests is finished, and also to catch any error (in the `catch` branch). So your code could be:

```
it('password_digest should not be empty', (done) => {
    User.create({
      email: 'aa@gmail.com',
      password: 'aa',
      password_confirmation: 'aa',
      role_id: 'User',
      profile_id: 'Consultant'
    })
    .then(function(user) {
      // your user assertions
      console.log(user);
      done();
    }).catch(done);
  });
```

Your current version of the test calls `done()` right after calling `User.create` so you're not giving time to the DB to perform the insertion.

Using as well `done` as your `catch` handlers ensures that any error in the promise chain doesn't stop your test from finishing, and has the benefit of printing the error for you. Calling `done()` with any value marks the test as failed.

Answer (score 1):

Your promise is presumably failing. You need to either check your error logs to find out what's up, or handle the failure case of your promise, with something like:

```
describe('Model:User - attribute: password_digest - unit tests', () => {
  it('password_digest should not be empty', (done) => {
    console.log('>>>1');
    console.log(User.create);
    User.create({
      email: 'aa@gmail.com',
      password: 'aa',
      password_confirmation: 'aa',
      role_id: 'User',
      profile_id: 'Consultant'
    }).then(function(user) {
      console.log('>>>2');
      console.log(user);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      // Ideally, every time you handle the success of a promise 
      // with `then`, you should also handle the possible failure 
      // of it with `catch` 
      console.log('Error inserting user:');
      console.log(err);
    });
    console.log('>>>3');
    done();
  });
});
```

Then, update your question with the specific error info and we can help you further.